# pgadmin4 installation Centos 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to get pgadmin4 installed on my Centos 7.6 machine, and I followed the below tuto :
https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-pgadmin-on-centos-fedora/

However, when I run:
'''
    python /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py
'''

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py", line 413, in
>   
>       setup_db()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py", line 347, in
>   setup_db
>       app = create_app()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/**init**.py",
>   line 711, in create_app
>       from flask_compress import Compress ImportError: No module named flask_compress

Any idea what I've missed ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `Flask-Compress`:

https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Compress/

Run the following command in your terminal:

`pip install Flask-Compress`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i managed to get 'initialization' using
    pip install Flask-Compress

However when running http://localhost/pgadmin
I get an internal server error (500), as follows:

''''

```
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174126 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13510): Target WSGI script '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174151 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224] mod_wsgi (pid=13510): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.wsgi'.
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174168 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174181 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.wsgi", line 36, in <module>
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174197 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224]     from pgAdmin4 import app as application
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174202 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.py", line 109, in <module>
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174210 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224]     app = create_app()
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174215 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 244, in create_app
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174222 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224]     create_app_data_directory(config)
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174226 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/setup/data_directory.py", line 42, in create_app_data_directory
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174234 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224]     os.chmod(config.SESSION_DB_PATH, 0o700)
[Tue Dec 17 15:27:04.174246 2019] [:error] [pid 13510] [remote ::1:224] OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/lib/pgadmin4/sessions'
```

''''

Comment: This is not how stack overflow works --- you ask a question and receive an answer -- if you have more questions then you post a new question -- not as an answer. If my answer helped, please upvote, mark as the answer and then post this new question on a different thread